# for loop behavior "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

I don't find an answer in the replies to this kind of question already been asked.
I don't understand, why console throws this error "***TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"*** , when my for-Loop contains this condition

```
  for (let i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
    arr.push(res[i].length);
  }
```

**Without equal sign** it works.

I don't get why. I thought setting i=1 would work. But it does not.
Could anyone explain please, why I get the error when given the condition

```
i>**=**res.length; (with equal sign)
```

Complete code

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  var arr = [];
  var res = str.split(" ");
  for (let i = 1; i < res.length; i++) {
    arr.push(res[i].length);
  }

  return Math.max(...arr);
}

findLongestWordLength("May the force be with you");
```

Thank you and happy new year.

Comment: Because array indexes start at `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because the index of an array is always length - 1.**

You can say. Suppose you have the array of length 2

`const ar = ["a", "b"]`

and if you check the length of this array it will show **2** but the max index of this array is **1** only.

So when you loop through the length of the array then it goes up to index 2 and `res[2]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Basically the indices of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) are zero based.

If you loop until the length, the last index is one over.

```
array = [1, 2, 3] // length === 3
```

If you loop until `3`,

```
array[3]
```

you get `undefined`, or if the element should be an object, then you get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero based in JavaScript.

For example: If you have 3 numbers in an array `var arr = [10,20,30]` then the indices of these numbers will be `0 1, 2` i.e. You can access `10` with `arr[0]`, `20` with `arr[1]` and `30` with `arr[2]`.

Note that length of this array will be 3. So when you iterate in your loop from 0 to length you go one index extra therefore you get `undefined`. Either go from `0 to <= res.length - 1` or `0 to < res` in your loop.