# Javascript for loop causing TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop that's causing a TypeError, but I'm not sure why.

```
for(var i =0; i<c.selection.length; i++) {
            arr.push(
                c.selection[i].id
            );
        }
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error?  I'm not using '<=' as indicated in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052561/for-loop-behavior-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) so I'm not sure where the code is going wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: what's in c.selection? It appears it doesnt exist at the time you're running the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because the `selection` property of your `c` object is undefined. Try to initialize it first.

```
let c = {
    selection: []
}
```

Comment: How do you know that? Wouldn't it be better to wait for a clarification of the OP first?

Comment: @JonasWilms Giving OP's context, this is what's happening. Once OP gives us more info about their problem, i will gladly update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas!  That did it, thanks for the explanation as well.